# Accessing XML payload of Metro 2.0 Request/Response Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I am developing a web service, using Metro 2.0 and Tomcat 6, and I have a requirement to be able to log the XML payload of the request and response of a web method for development/support reasons.  The payload would only be logged when in debug mode.

The Web Service uses a servlet implementation (com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet  and .WSServletContextListener classes), if that affects the answer.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting these system properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.assembler.client=true
```

The SOAP messages go to system out, which I believe Tomcat logs.

Comment: I have set these 2 values by way of System.setProperty() method and nothing is being logged.  I am running tomcat within eclipse (which of course runs the tomcat instance inside the WST plugin directory) and invoking it using the Web Services Explorer.  There are no files in the workspace/plugins/.../logs directory and nothing new on the console.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: They need to be defined in the invocation of the JVM.  I have too seen that using System.setProperty did not work.

Comment: Yeah it's working fine thanks - I need to create scripts to start Tomcat in release/debug mode and I'm now looking how to control the debug setting of Logback using a similar mechanism....  cheers -A

Comment: logback supports "tasting" on system properties and conditional evaluations.

Comment: There is now the possibility that I need the XML payload of the request and response in order to log it directly to the database!  A .net programmer at work thinks I can get this using an interceptor or message handler?  Is that true when using Metro 2?

Comment: I do not immediately know.  I would suggest opening a new question.